# Call a function in AFNetworking async block

Tags: ios, function, afnetworking

i have many server requests in my app so i trying to set an JasonParser class that will handle my AFNetworking requests.

here is my function:

```
- (void)startParseWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)incomingParameters andUrlAdress:(NSString*)urlAdress {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = incomingParameters;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [manager POST:urlAdress parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


         NSString *recivedErr = responseObject[@"error"];
        [weakSelf didReceiveResponse:[recivedErr integerValue];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

-(void)didReceiveResponse:(NSInteger)status {
}
```

but the function 'didReceiveResponse' called before the block is finished so i could't get the value.
there is any way to handle it?

Comment: You mean `didReceiveResponse` is called before your request has finished ?

Comment: yes.. thats what i said.

Comment: "before the block is finished" and "before your request is finished" is not the same. Have you tried to look the stack trace by adding a breakpoint in your 'didReceiveResponse' ?

Comment: yes.. the function 'didReceiveResponse' called before the async request is finished so in that point i dont have the vaule so i always get 0.

Comment: what did the stack trace say ?